# One intent for Multiple Questions - Amazon Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Can i use a single intent to give response to different question.

For eg :

Suppose i have a intent **reports**, now for **reports** there can be multiple questions like

Q1 . How to download report?

Q2 . Where can i see my reports?

> Do i have to make separate intent for **download reports** and **show
>   reports** and call a single lambda function for fulfillment? I can
>   have nested if else for intents to give a suitable response.

Is there any other way i can minimize my no of intents ? I am using JavaScript for lambda function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In Alexa and Lex lingo: "Utterance" = user questions or statements.)

**General Tip when deciding to group or separate intents:**
Use multiple intents when the utterances differ greatly.
Use a single intent when you have similar utterances and only a few words differ between them.

If the utterances are similar then you can use `slots` to determine the keyword differences.

Here's how to set it up using your example:

Create a single intent called `Records`.
Then create a custom `slotType` called `actionTypes` and list the values as: (`download`, `see`, `view`, etc)
Then add a `slot` to `Records` called `action` using `actionTypes` as the slotType.

Your utterances then become:

```
 how do I {action} reports  
 how do I {action} a report  
 where can I {action} my reports
```

Then in your Lambda and within your `Records` handling logic, you can detect the `action` slot and respond accordingly.

This is much better in your case than parsing `inputTranscript` yourself. Let Lex do that as much as possible, it's what Lex is meant for.

Comment: What if the utterances are not similar but falls under reports category, then i have to make another intent right? For eg : show me reports for last 2 days.

Comment: You could always make a new intent. But you can also get tricky with unrequired slots, "{action} my reports for {date}" and use AMAZON.Date slotType. That would accept a wide variety of date-related phrases like "yesterday" or "two days ago", and provide you with an actual date stamp "yyyy-mm-dd" to query your databse with.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend not to do that as that is not a good design but is possible to do with one Intent and two questions as in the input JSON you will to the Lambda will have the question you have asked along with the intent. If you see the below JSON, which is the format of Lex to your Lambda function (or other endpoints). The field 'inputTranscript' will have the question you have asked. You can write an if condition check against the field 'inputTranscript' in your code and the can respond the corresponding answer.

As I told I recommend not to do that as Intent means what is the intention. Two different question means two different intents.

```js
{
  "messageVersion": "1.0",
  "invocationSource": "FulfillmentCodeHook",
  "userId": "876669698689967676",
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "requestAttributes": null,
  "bot": {
    "name": "LexBotName",
    "alias": "$LATEST",
    "version": "$LATEST"
  },
  "outputDialogMode": "Text",
  "currentIntent": {
    "name": "WorkingHours",
    "slots": {},
    "slotDetails": {},
    "confirmationStatus": "None"
  },
  "inputTranscript": "The question you have asked"
}
```